# Model, View e Controller "Multiuso" - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, laravel-5

Bom dia, tenho em minha aplicação umas 10 tabelas diferentes, mas que tem a mesma estrutura... `id` | `nome` | `descricao`. Para cada tabela tenho no laravel o `Model`, o `Controller` e as `Views` de cadastro, listagem e edição. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de usar um mesmo `Model`, `Controller` e `View` para gerenciar isso tudo, ou se tem como minimizar isso de alguma forma, pois tem muitos arquivos parecidos e não acho que isso seja realmente necessário, apenas me falta conhecimento.

Comment: Talvez, com um pouco de criatividade, isso possa te ajudar https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, não sei ao certo se é a melhor solução, mas me caiu muito bem...
Apenas juntei todas as tabelas e adicionei uma coluna "tipo". Como o volume de dados de cada uma é bem baixo acho que funcionará bem.

Comment: Criar uma tabela que tenha uma coluna adicional 'tipo' no lugar de muitas com estrutura semelhante é de mais fácil manutenção e implementação, hoje são 10 tabelas futuramente esse número multiplica :)